# Translation of "respond" in medical treatments

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

What is the right translation of *respond* in the following context. A foreign learner like me perhaps will use "antworten" but I'not sure that makes any sense.

> A nonsurgical treatment plan is developed and executed. Some patients respond well, and others do not. One patient comes back for reevaluation and significant disease resolution has occurred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In German it is *auf eine Behandlung [ansprechen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ansprechen#Bedeutung7a)*.

Comment: Auf eine Behandlung _reagieren_ ginge auch, aber _ansprechen_ ist definitiv das bessere Wort.